# How does Instagram's javascript work?

Tags: javascript, python, web-crawler, instagram

I'm trying to build a Python web crawler that could get Instagram's photos, like the Instagram's official insta: "instagram.com/instagram" . The initial web source only contains latest 20 photos, the others need to scroll down to load. As a Javascript freshman, I can't figure out how does Instagram load these via Javascript.

In my observation, there are two JS scripts that might relate to the load action which are [webpack-common.js](http:////instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/10ec832/cache/bundles/en_US_webpack-common.js) and [UserProfile.js](http:////instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/10ec832/cache/bundles/en_US_UserProfile.js) . Check when hit the bottom of page and then make an ajax call to get new data.

But how to do that via crawler? I'v download these js files and load them using PyV8 but always got errors. Do I need to do more than just execute the js files?

Comment: Better have a look at the structure of the AJAX calls themselves, instead of trying to emulate the whole page

Comment: My advice: avoid the crawler altogether and use the [Instagram API](https://instagram.com/developer/).  There's even a handy [Python library](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram).

Comment: Thank you @Alec Ananian . I'v considered Instagram API but they have rule :"You cannot use the Instagram API to crawl or store users' media without their express consent." Though I just want to practice my Python and will not do anything with these photos, it still not good to do that through Instagram API, I think.

Comment: Probably these files have some external dependencies like libraries, most javascript files are not stand-alone.

Comment: @JinhuanLi Also in the terms: `You must not access Instagram's private API by means other than those permitted by Instagram.`  Either way you're breaking the terms of use.  Integrating with an API might be a better use of your Python-practicing time too because it'll introduce you to more real world developer scenarios.